# How to take screenshot of video call in quickblox android sdk 2.5.2?

Tags: android, quickblox-android

how to extract local media stream from the session in order to work with the local video(camera). I would like to extract the video/frames from the session (the local videostream) to further process (save image as bitmap) or how to take a screenshot of RTCGLVideoView(camera view)?

Comment: We've been trying to do that for weeks and still no luck. however, ooVoo provides this but still it would be great if quickblox could resolve this issue